# why python replace first few characters?

Tags: python

I am writing a python script.
I init a parameter

```
self._outpu_path = ''
```

and set value by OptionParser, with the value

```
/Users/huaxingzheng/projects/test
```

and then I defined an output file name string

```
FILE_NAME = "resource_map.lua"
```

then I concat the string

```
lua_file_full_path = "{0}/{1}".format(self._outpu_path, FILE_NAME)
```

when I print the `lua_file_full_path` variable, it shows

```
/resource_map.luang/projects/test
```

which means it replace the first few characters.

I used the `+` operator, join and something else to fix that, but it doesn't works, would someone knows the reason? Thanks vary much.

------------------------ MORE DETAIL------------------------

when I print the variable self._output_path
it prints that:

```
/Users/huaxingzheng/projects/test
```

then I set a new variable

```
OUTPUT_PATH = "/Users/huaxingzheng/projects/test"
```

then I found they are not the same, because

```
len(self._output_path)
```

shows `34`

while

```
len(OUTPUT_PATH)
```

shows `33`

Comment: Are you sure there are no backslashes somewhere in your string? Please provide [MCVE] - something that's copy-pasteable to interpreter.

Comment: could you show all your code

Comment: note: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For joining paths, use the standard [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) function:

```
import os

lua_file_full_path = os.path.join(self._outpu_path, FILE_NAME)
```

Comment: The OP is interested in knowing the reason. While `os.path.join` is the preferred way of joining paths, it will produce exactly the same result as `"{0}/{1}".format` in this particular case (on Unix systems). This really should have been posted as comment, or not posted at all, since Wayne already linked to that page.

Comment: I use the function at the very first time, it's not this reason ^_^